# how to organize the mulit-application in django

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a project with many models in different application. I'm confused that if I want to write some functions which will use some models in other applications, how should I organize the function file. Does I create new app like service and put all similar file in it  Or put the file in the app. Here is example:

```
proj
 - command
   -- models
   ....
 - host
   -- models
   ...
 - metrics
   -- models
   ....
```

if I want to write a function which execute given command on given host and insert the result into metric database, where should i put the function in the views.py of host app or in new file named service.py. And if i create new file named service.py, where should i put, in new application or host application?

```
 proj
 - command
   -- models
   ....
 - host
   -- models
   -- service
   ...
 - metrics
   -- models
   ....
```

OR

```
proj
 - command
   -- models
   ....
 - host
   -- models
   ...
 - metrics
   -- models
   ....
 - service
   -- hostService.py
```

if I want to write a function which execute given command on given host and insert the result into metric database, where should i put the function in the views.py of host app or in new file named service.py. And if i create new file named service.py, where should i put, in new application or host application?

```
 proj
 - command
   -- models
   ....
 - host
   -- models
   -- service
   ...
 - metrics
   -- models
   ....
```

Thanks in advance